# How do I capture a specific word on a bash screen using Python?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7

I am new to python, while executing a shell command, I get an output, say for example:

[t@centos conf]$ show images

REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED

ap-11aug-latest       latest              c070f30df2bd        9 weeks ago

hello-world           latest              af340544ed62        9 weeks ago

where REPOSITORY,TAG,IMAGE,ID and CREATED are columns headers.

Now, I want to copy say for example the text `ap-11aug-latest` which is there in the second row and first column, how can I capture it using Python? Space is the delimiter.

I basically want to capture the text that comes in a that position i.e 2nd row and first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little code snippet will execute your command in a subprocess, and will give you the possibility to capture the standard output.

```
import subprocess

def get_stdout(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    result = []
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    while line != '':
        tag = line.split(' ')[0]
        print(tag)
        line = p.stdout.readline()
get_stdout('show images')
```

If you only want the first column of the second line, you can do that:

```
import subprocess

def get_stdout(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    result = []
    p.stdout.readline() # reads the first line
    line = p.stdout.readline() # reads the second line
    tag = line.split(' ')[0]
    print(tag)
get_stdout('show images')
```

Comment: Thanks! This snippet retrieves the first column. The out put will be : REPOSITORY
ap-11aug-latest
hello-world                                                                                                           Now, I need the text that is on the second line. So, I will retrieve the text that is present on the second line of the first column. What should I tweak to retrieve only "ap-11aug-latest" in this case?